# Trying to get a worksheet names from an excel with LinqToExcel

Tags: c#, linq-to-excel

I trying to load worksheet names from an excel using LinqToExcel.

using the following line of code

`excelQueryFactory.GetWorksheetNames();`

The worksheet names are ["$2,00","$5.00"].

but load ["2,00" , "5,00"]. The $ sign is missing.

What i do wrong? . How could i load the sush as they are?

Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7232960/how-do-i-use-linqtoexcel-to-get-sheet-names-of-an-excel-file

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue and looking a bit at the code I found that the function "GetWorksheetNames()" replaces some symbols including "$". You can see it [here](https://github.com/paulyoder/LinqToExcel/blob/master/src/LinqToExcel/Query/ExcelUtilities.cs)